# Show image when text link is hovered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, hyperlink

I have a menu and I want to show images when a user hovers over a link. 
By now I have tried CSS and JavaScript but I still seem to have problems.

With html and css, images seem to hide each other.
With JS all the images are shown at first, when the page is loaded.
It works OK otherwise.

Any help is greatly appreciated, as I struggled with this a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Both display:none and overflow:hidden did the trick! Greatly appreciated.

Comment: why not set the opacity of the images on first load to 0.01 (so they still load...)? Or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

on the second link to the page_id=1401 looks like you need to set to overflow to hidden.

try changing the full class starting on line 2208 in your CSS file to

```
.full {
width: 100%;
height: 465px;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the second example, you could add `style="display: none;"` to divs *one* through *seven*.
Right now they're visible on load, but this will hide them on load.

Comment: Both display:none and overflow:hidden did the trick!!! Thanks very much!!! You saved me from another sleepless night!! Greatly appreciated.